# Why is html_entity_decode() working for the first string, but not the second?

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, character, decoding

```
$string1 = 'Cotton Lanyard &frac12;"';
$string2 = 'Organic Cotton Lanyard &frac58;"';

echo html_entity_decode($string1); //Cotton Lanyard ½"
echo html_entity_decode($string2); //Organic Cotton Lanyard &frac58;"
```

Not really sure how to fix this?

Comment: I think you charset is the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works with an HTML5 document type [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php#refsect1-function.html-entity-decode-parameters).

```
echo html_entity_decode($string2, ENT_HTML5);   // Organic Cotton Lanyard ⅝"
```

Since the default type is `ENT_HTML401` (HTML 4.01), I suppose that means the ⅝ entity isn't defined there.

Comment: on my setup, copy/paste OP code gives the correct result

Comment: @Ggg interesting. I pasted it into 3v4l.org to verify, and the original code showed the same behavior as OP observed

Comment: I have ⅝'s coming though in php. But when I convert to json and store it as a JS variable it becomes the &frac58; code.

Comment: @AlexDonnelly you mean after converting with `html_entity_decode` as in your question, you use `json_encode` on the string with ⅝, and it shows up in the JSON as &frac58;? I would think you'd actually get \u215d, unless you used `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. Or maybe I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: @Don't Panic Let me be more clear.
I originally asked this question because I saw im my javascript variable output that I was getting "Organic Cotton Lanyard &frac58" instead of my expected " Organic Cotton Lanyard ⅝".

So I though, okay theres a problem with the PHP. But I realized on the php side that html_entity_decode was actually working and was generating "Organic Cotton Lanyard ⅝" like I expected. But when I add this to a JS variable it goes back to &frac58;

Comment: @Don'tPanic The code i'm using 

$prodData = getProductData(); //Organic Cotton Lanyard ⅝"
prodData = <?=$simpleProductData ?>; //Organic Cotton Lanyard &frac58;"

Comment: @AlexDonnelly okay, so how does `$prodData` get to `$simpleProductData`? just `json_encode($prodData)`, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sorry Im messing up my replies. 
$simpleProductData = getProductData(); //This function returns the array/string json encoded like so return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($arr);

Then in the JS...
 simpleProductData = <?= $simpleProductData ?>;

Comment: @AlexDonnelly maybe it's something that happens in jsonEncoder->encode(). Are you using a framework, or is that a method you wrote as well?

Comment: @Don'tPanic First off just wanted to thank you for your effort. The result of echoing $simpleProductData, which returns the encoded json, gives me `("bold_name":"Organic Cotton Lanyard ⅝\"",` So I don't think the jsonEncoder is the problem